# Is PHP editing the page just for the client?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a Cordova app, and I inserted in it an Iframe connected to a PHP page. I want that the page to look different for each user, so I want to ask you: If I run a the user runs a PHP on the page from the Iframe, will it change the page for all users?
Example: the initial page contains just a text,let's say Hello.
User 1 runs some actions that transform that text to Welcome​. If in the same time, user 2 also sees the page from his Iframe, what will he see? Hello or Welcome?
I hope the question was pretty clear, please be patient.

Comment: Unless you save the changes to a database and serve that new page to others, anything a user is doing on a browser will not be seen by others . But do visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Your question is off topic since it lacks effort and code

Comment: Do you have any knowledge with server side programming ?

Comment: PHP is ran on the server and *generates* an HTML page that gets delivered to the user's browser.  Each user will get their own PHP "instance" so each user's output can be different depending on what the PHP code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page must persist this change somehow.

How web works:

1 - User makes a request to a PHP page;

2 - Server receives a request prepares the response and delivery it back to the client;

3 - The client receives the page and displays it.

So, you need in this step 2 make your PHP prepare a different page to attend each users request;

lets dive deep into step 2:

// preparing the page (hypothetical)

2.1 read the database previous value

2.2 calc the new value

2.3 store this new value to database

2.4 print the page with new calculated value

As you can see, every new request will get a new calculated value based on previous value that was stored somehow (in this hypothetical example: a database)

I hope this clear the things for you

Comment: I don't think he *wants* to persist the change.  I think he was just asking *if* it did since he may have no knowledge of PHP.

Comment: Thank you sir, now I understand